# Android SQLite multiple databases and CRUD

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to implement databases linked with **foreign keys** and I've been told it's better (more secure) to stick to queries instead of rawQueries in general, but I'm unsure how far. What's the best approach to CRUD operations; to use multiple queries (`.query(.)`) or use more sophisticated rawQueries?

**For example**

If I want to delete a row from a table iff there is no other table linking to that particular row.

Or are there perhaps better ways when constructing the database that makes such operations smoother?

Also, when inserting into a table and there's already a row (and the column is unique or similar restraint), is there a quick way to find the rowId of the value being inserted regardless of whether or not it was inserted or already exists?

```
I tried `insertWithOnConflict(.)`
```

but it throws -1 instead of the rowId when already exists. Is there a better way than to execute another query afterwards upon failure?

Comment: **1** - "Queries" are the **R** part of C**R**UD. **C**, **U** and **D** are "commands". **2** - Queries use `rawQuery()` or `query()` (your choice). Commands use `execSQL()` or `insert(), update() or delete()` (again, your choice). **3** - I'd use a `rawQuery()` with a `REPLACE INTO` command.

Comment: Please ask only one question: [ask]

Comment: Ehm... sorry, my fault (I just finished saying that you don't use `rawQuery` for commands) - I'd use an `execSQL()` with a `REPLACE INTO` command.